# Netlogo: input a probability through a slider

Tags: netlogo

I want to input a probability value in the code through a slider. The name of the slider is lawful-industry with a value range from 0 to 1, so the code I wrote is:

```
 [let probs [["lawful" lawful-industry]["unlawful" 1 - lawful-industry]]
```

but NetLogo outputs "Expected a literal value". What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give more context for this code? What are you expecting `probs` to be in this example- a list of lists? If that's the case, you need to use the `list` primitive since you are making a list from interface inputs. Try this:

```
to test
  let probs list ( list "lawful" lawful-industry ) ( list "unlawful" ( 1 - lawful-industry ) )
  print probs
end
```

Output (when `lawful-industry` is 0.37):

```
[[lawful 0.37] [unlawful 0.63]]
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, you answered my question.